# How to implement a variable in Jet SQL INSERT INTO clause

Tags: sql, insert, jet, insert-into

Is there a method in MS Access Jet SQL to implement a substitution variable so that the executor can input their own new Table name?  See SQL below:

```
SELECT 
  Subset.FacNo, 
  Subset.BldgNum, 
  Subset.Qrate AS Qrate, 
  Subset.MaxOfSqFt AS SqFeet, 
  Subset.Frate AS Frate 
INTO [Enter Table Name]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    FacNo, 
    Qrate, 
    Frate, 
    MAX(SqFeet) AS MaxOfSqFt, 
    Replace(LTrim(Replace([FacNo],"0"," "))," ","0") AS BldgNum 
  FROM ISR_Q3_2013_webdata 
  GROUP BY 
    FACNO, 
    Qrate, 
    Frate
 )  AS Subset;
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: For access, I think you just stick a '?' in the query (without the single quotes)

Comment: No, just tried that.  Where the [Enter Table Name] is there needs to be a variable such as $TABLENAME or @TableName  Allowing the user to type in the name of a new table.